# Как решить данную проблему с безрамочным окном в Electron js?

Tags: javascript, electron

Возникла проблема с безрамочным окном в **Electron js v 17.1.2**
не могу вернуть развёрнутое окно в изначальное состояние, 
в разделе документации **BrowserWindow** описаны следующие методы:

> Событие: '**isMaximized**' Возвращает boolean - если окно развернуто; 
> Событие: '**maximize**'  Происходит, когда окно увеличивается до предела; 
> Событие: '**unmaximize**' Происходит, когда окно выходит из увеличенного состояния; 
> Событие: '**restore**' Происходит, когда окно восстанавливается из свернутого состояния.

Но по какойто причине **isMaximized**, **unmaximize** и **restore** не в какую не хотят работать
а вот **maximize**, **minimize**, **close** работают как должны. 
Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным, зарание спасибо за помощь.

Вот мой код:

```
const minimizeButton = document.getElementById('minimize');
const maximizeButton = document.getElementById('maximize');
const closeButton = document.getElementById('close-app');

minimizeButton.addEventListener('click', minimize);
maximizeButton.addEventListener('click', maximize);
closeButton.addEventListener('click', close_app);

let isMaximized = false;
function close_app () {
    app.window.close();
}
function maximize () {
    isMaximized = !isMaximized;
    isMaximized ? app.window.maximize() : app.window.unmaximize();
}
function minimize () {
    app.window.minimize();
}
```

> preload.js :

```
import { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } from 'electron'
const API = {
    window: {
        close: () => ipcRenderer.send('app/close'),
        minimize: () => ipcRenderer.send('app/minimize'),
        maximize: () => ipcRenderer.send('app/maximize'),
    },
    getVersion : () => ipcRenderer.invoke("GET/version")
}

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("app", API)
```

> main.js :

```
ipcMain.on('app/close', () => {
  app.quit();
})
ipcMain.on('app/minimize', () => {
  window.minimize();
})
ipcMain.on('app/maximize', () => {
  window.maximize();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось когда выспался и вернулся к коду я понял что забыл передать эти методы  **isMaximized**, **unmaximize** и **restor** в main.js :

```
ipcMain.on('app/maximize', () => {
  window.isMaximized() ? window.unmaximize() : window.maximize()
})
```